# I can not boot ubuntu 12.04

Tags: boot-repair

I have installed windows xp after installed ubuntu 12.04. Now I am unable to boot ubuntu. I have used Boot-Repair, but no use. I got the following http://paste.ubuntu.com/6509719/.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes GRUB is responsible by this.
Here is one possible solution:
1. Re-install Ubuntu
2. When it asks for password check "Log me in automatically", sometimes grub messes up when it requests a password.
3. Shutdown, and boot your PC again.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Log in into your windows xp os.Download and install EasyBCD from [*`here`*.](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html)
- Open Easybcd.Under linux section select grub2 as bootloader and then add a boot entry for your Ubuntu Partition.And also add entry for your *windows xp* partition.
- reboot you pc.Now you can select both windows and ubuntu os on startup.